# Nucleus vibration

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, frequency, subatomic, order-of-magnitude

What are the frequencies of the vibrations of the atom's nucleus? Is it in the quadrillions? Vibrating molecules is not the same thing - which is addressed as phonon vibration.

Comment: Start somewhere like https://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.32.1

Answer (score 1):

For a nucleus with medium mass, the first excited vibrational state is typically at an excitation energy of about 1 MeV. We can relate this to a frequency via $E=\hbar \omega$, which gives $\omega\sim10^{21}$ Hz. This is what is known as an isoscalar vibration, in which neutrons and protons move together.

> Vibrating molecules is not the same thing - which is addressed as phonon vibration.

Both can be described in terms of phonons. Phonons are a general way of thinking about any quantum-mechanical vibration: they act like bosonic excitations.

Comment: The term "resonance" is what I often see, instead of "vibrations or oscillations".  If something is in resonance with something, what form does that resonance take - vibration and oscillation, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from  https://www.accessscience.com/content/giant-nuclear-resonances/288700 :

Elementary modes of oscillation of the whole nucleus, closely related to the normal modes of oscillation of coupled mechanical systems. Giant nuclear resonances occur systematically in most, if not all, nuclei, with oscillation energies typically in the range of 10–30 MeV. Among the best-known examples is the giant electric dipole (E1) resonance, in which all the protons and all the neutrons oscillate with opposite phase, producing a large time-varying electric dipole moment which acts as an effective antenna for radiating gamma rays.

Comment: APS, Physics Review Letters, and other such publications aren't open to someone who isn't a fellow of a university or other professional organization, or can afford membership -- people like me. So, these forum-like sites are our "go to" sources for more technical / advanced information.

Comment: This excerpt answers your question in my opinion. I agree that these paywall should not exist.

Comment: Also, see https://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-th/9807012

Comment: That link actually worked.  The anticipated article opened. It has as much information, for now, I desire.